# How to make the try function only print my message once

Tags: python-3.x

I've tried using the try() function, but when i try: and then type print() it just prints the message non-stop. how do i make it only print once?

```
def inputInt(minv, maxv, message):
    res = int(input(message))
    while (res > minv) and (res < maxv):
        try:
            print("Good job.")
        except:
            print("Invalid input")
```

Comment: why do you need try/catch here at all?

Comment: The reason why it is printing non-stop is because of the while loop. As the two conditions are not updating inside the loop, the conditions are always true. That's why it kept printing

Comment: Shouldn't `res = int(input(message))` be also in your `while` loop? Otherwise `res` will never get updated. And actually @Andyk. ' s comment is more than relevant!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with `break`?

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199065/how-to-get-out-of-a-try-except-inside-a-while-python) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758029/try-block-inside-while-statement) to get more clarification, but if you want that at the one time the try jumps to the except, it should print it once only, `break`is the thing.

I must say this loop will go on forever as you are not changing `res`. Even if it goes in the `try` or in the `except`.

Answer (score 1):

The code that could raise an exception should be in the `try`.  The input should be inside the `while`.  Catch expected exceptions in case an unexpected exception occurs.  A naked `except` is bad practice and can hide errors.

Here's a suggested implementation:

```
def inputInt(minv, maxv, message):
    while True: # Loop until break
        try:
            res = int(input(message)) # Could raise ValueError if input is not an integer.
            if minv <= res <= maxv:   # if res is valid,
                break                 #    exit while loop
        except ValueError:            # Ignore ValueError exceptions
            pass
        print("Invalid input")        # if didn't break, input or res was invalid.
    return res                        # Once while exits, res is good

x = inputInt(5,10,"enter number between 5 and 10: ")
```